# Share large data between host and docker container process

Tags: ubuntu, docker, networking, large-files

There are 10000+ large data files (several Gigabytes for each file) on host, few of them which may be used in the docker containers and containers may create new files to save to host (there may 100+ containers and all containers are on the same host machine). But we do not want mount the data files to the docker for security consideration.

Is is a high performance way to share large files between host and container? e.g. write a server on host to send or receive large data from container process? Or use mmap? Or sendfile? (OS: ubuntu 16, and python is preferred)

Comment: Ceph is fairly normal use, but that might be overkill. If setting up some kind of distributed bockstorage is out of the question you might want to use a service provider that supports this already.